# Add software bin or just add soft link for executable file in bin when install software on linux?

Tags: linux, installation, software-design, slurm

I’m not root for the linux server,
so I choose to install softwares in my `$HOME/local/bin`, I already added the `$HOME/local/bin` directory to the PATH environment variable, wrote in my `.bashrc`.

Some softwares install this way like:

```
tar xvzf ncurses-5.9.tar.gz
cd ncurses-5.9
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local
make
make install
cd ..
```

So it will directly install in my `$HOME/local/bin`.

But for some softwares, after download like `sbt-1.2.1.zip` (based on java), and decompression, shows just a file fold `sbt`, it contains three folds`bin  conf  lib`, and in its `bin`, contains one executable file named `sbt` and `java9-rt-export.jar sbt-launch-lib.bash  sbt-launch.jar  sbt.bat`.

**Here I wonder:**

- I should just soft link this executable `sbt` file path under my     `$HOME/local/bin`, then source my `.bashrc`?
     Or, after    decompression, add one line in my .bashrc    `export    PATH="downloadpath/sbt/bin:$PATH"`?
     Since just one executable    `downloadpath/sbt/bin`, so I'm not    sure it is right to add whole bin fold    path, if software's bin    fold contains executable files (one or    many), I think this    situation is more convenient for just add it's bin in    .bashrc, but    even so, I'm not sure its right?
- I'm not familiar with installation software, now I usually know way
  but not why. Here I shows two ways (more ways not be showed here) to
  install, executable file always be written in bin or src? But some
  softwares no bin just src but no executable files in it...
- Slurm also can use modules to install software, conda also other way, but I want to
  confirm these traditional ways I mentioned (that two) still can be
  used on slurm or conda?

However, any suggestion even one aspect's reminding will be grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For precompiled software, or, in general, software that does not offer configure scripts or (C)make files, it is ofter better to leave them in their target directory and adapt the `*PATH` (`PATH` to binaries, but also `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `LIBRARY_PATH` to libraries and `CPATH` to include files and `MANPATH` to the man page)  environment variables.

The reason is that the software might be configured to read files with hardcoded paths, relative to the position of the executable, such as libraries, etc.

In your case, you might also need to setup the `CLASSPATH` env variable to the directory with the `jar` files.

To ease software installation, you can use tools such as [easybuild](https://easybuild.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that can help, and even create user modules just like the system module installed by the system administrators.

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong in my opinion with your setup. If you don`t have root account on your server, is not better to test what you have to test, in a more safe environment - for example a vm/container on your developement machine ?
However, in your situation maybe it can be  better to start sbt by using a separate bash script than modifying your .bashrc

Comment: "using a separate bash script" means...?

Comment: ... a file similar to .bashrc but with other name.
In order for your setup to work, you have to make some changes, as detailed by @damienfrancois. In my opinion is better to make those modifications regarding your environment into a bash script (named for example myCustomStartupEnv.sh ) rather than editing yuour .bashrc. This will allow you to test, modify and suit your environment without affecting global configuration and also to be able to quick change the "custom" environment without restarting terminal between tests.